# git checkout master command gives error that a file would be overwritten

Tags: ios, git

I just made tried to do git checkout master and I got this error:

```
macoss-MacBook-Pro-10:Marketing owner12$ git checkout master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    Marketing.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/owner12.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

but I am not sure how to handle this situation. I don't mind having this file overwritten by what is in the repo.  What is the correct way for me to proceed here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have files that are not being tracked. Either

`rm untracked.file1 untracked.file2`

or

`git add . && git commit -m "adding new previously untracked files that serve a purpose"`

if you're having permission issues:

`git add --ignore-errors .`

Comment: thank you. It almost worked. I am on the branch I need now, but for some reason when I tried to commit one of the files, I got a permission denied - would you know why that would happen?

Answer (score 1):

Either delete the file if you don't care about it or stash it if you think you will need it in the future.  Or simply rename.

Comment: thank you. It almost worked. I am on the branch I need now, but for some reason when I tried to commit one of the files, I got a permission denied - would you know why that would happen?

Answer (score 1):

Commit the files you want to keep and then do a git clean to remove the extra files you don't want to keep. This [article](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/16/cleaning-up-untracked-files.html) on the git ready website describes it very well.

If you just want to get rid of one or two files in your working directory then you can do a dry run first and see which files would be cleaned up using:

```
git clean -n
```

And then when you are sure do this:

```
git clean -f
```

git clean has a -d switch if you want to clean up directories as well. And you can use that together with the other switches, so this is what I would normally use (and then after the dry run change -n to -f):

```
git clean -n -d
```

Then after your git clean, use:

```
git status
```

to make sure that you have no untracked files or uncommitted changes. And lastly switch to master with:

```
git checkout master
```